# How do i remove the large leading space in the output of this code for variable a

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm experimenting with string and string replacement for example in application to strip bad language or malicious code characters from strings . this is working but the output when compiled leaves a large space prior to the output "vilification managed..."

```
//import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class grandaddy {
public static void main (String [ ] args) {

//"now that the k's in place where the c used to be" (now it's on)  

String tempinvarate= "marduk";
String sminth= "subparticle";
String infiltrate= "cosmicwind";
tempinvarate=tempinvarate.replace ("k", "c");
String a= "piss shit !@£$%^* vilification managed";
String b=" by mark scorfield";
a= a.replace("piss", "");
a= a.replace("shit", "");
a= a.replaceAll("[^a-z-A-Z0-9]", " ");
a=a+b;
System.out.println(tempinvarate); 
System.out.println(tempinvarate.replace("k", "c"));
System.out.println(sminth);
System.out.println(sminth.replace("sub", "sminth"));
System.out.println(infiltrate);
System.out.println(infiltrate.replace("cosmic" , "minute"));
//int n = a.length();
//Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");
//String[] arr = SPACE.split(a);
//String[] splitStr = a.trim().split("\\s+");
System.out.println(a);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading spaces are for multiple reasons:

- When you remove expletives, they are surrounded by spaces, that are not removed. You could capture your expletives using the following regex instead:

  ```
  \baaaa[^a-zA-Z]?
  ```

  This regex will capture a word boundary, followed by the expletive (replaced with `aaaa` here), and then an optional non-alphanumeric character. If you want to match `aaaa` inside a word (e.g. xaaaa) then remove the word boundary `\b`.
- Your replacement of `[^a-z-A-Z0-9]` replaces them with a space. You can replace with an empty string instead:

  ```
  a= a.replaceAll("[^a-z-A-Z0-9]", "");
  ```

  However, you will notice that now *all* spaces are stripped and you get `vilificationmanaged`... This is easily worked around by allowing spaces (I also use `+` to capture and remove a bunch of characters at a time, out of habit):

  ```
  a= a.replaceAll("[^a-z-A-Z0-9 ]+", "");
  ```

After these changes, a string `A quick brown fox jumps over the aaaa lazy &^&% dog` will become `A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`.

Comment: This looks like a comprehensive way to continue developing. many thanks.